# How do you disable Super Secret Settings on Minecraft 1.8?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do you disable the SuperSecretSettings in Minecraft?  I have tried F4, spam clicking, everything.  My version is 1.8. I never knew what it was, and now I can't disable it.

Comment: Why do we need a capital letter at the start of every word?

Comment: In the English language we use capital letters at the start of sentences and in proper nouns. Not every word.

Comment: Its Like Shouting For An Answer, Without Looking Like You Are Shouting

Answer (score 1):

To sum up what other have posted in the linked threads:

---

**1.** Spam clicking doesn't always work.

**2.** Pressing <kbd>F4</kbd> doesn't always work, try doing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>.

**3.** One sure method is to just close out of Minecraft and restart the game.