# All blocks look blurry

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So, I had to factory reset my laptop and then I had to download everything again. I play modded Minecraft, so I had to download Forge mod loader and all the mods again. After I got all the mods together, I started Minecraft again but all the blocks and textures look REALLY blurry.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: looks like you have one of the "special effects" on. I don't remember what it's called. It was in the menu at some point.

Comment: Definitely looks like a shader of some kind. I suggest removing mods one at a time to see which one is causing the issue.

Comment: ok so heres what happens- the problem comes from toggle sneak mod. Whenever I change the position of the display HUD, things start messing up..otherwise, they are good..I have tried multiple toggle sneak mods but none of them work..

Comment: @MartianCactus If you have figured out your problem, you should post it as an answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because tech support for modded Minecraft is off-topic here.

Comment: @Gigazelle Voting to leave open as per [What exactly is technical support?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11015/4797)

Answer (score 1):

As Karlyr already mentioned you have accidently turned on one of the "Super Secret Settings". Go to

> Options > Graphic Settings > Super Secret Settings

Try to click as long as the game looks normal again or have a look at this:
[How do you disable Super Secret Settings on Minecraft 1.8?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/190307/how-do-you-disable-super-secret-settings-on-minecraft-1-8)

Comment: ok so heres what happens- the problem comes from toggle sneak mod. Whenever I change the position of the display HUD, things start messing up..otherwise, they are good..I have tried multiple toggle sneak mods but none of them work..

Comment: actually....the toggle sprint/sneak doesnt even work..and when i go to its options, it starts messing things up..

Answer (score 0):

you are getting image something like this:
[image]

**Assuming** you have installed **shaders mod(till 1.8.x)** or **optifine(1.9+)**,
some mod must have reduced the resolution(probably due to low FPS?)
you could do is increase the resolution
from

[image] to [image]

Comment: no i don't use shaders

Answer (score 0):

I have figured the problem, the toggleSprint mod was the problem so I just used the BetterSprint mod. I don't use any shaders..